# Dump mysql view as a table with data - version 2

Tags: view, mysql

Q: Is there a way to direct MYSQLDUMP to export VIEW's with data (and not just the CREATE SQL)?  I want to use the resulting SQL to create a new table.

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 0):

I don't know method how to dump only view without table. But you could try next method:

1. Run next command from shell:

   mysql -u[username] -p[password] -e "SHOW CREATE VIEW [view_name]" > [view_name]_dump.sql
2. Then modify generated sql script manually.